# Parse lines in files with similar strings using Python

Tags: python, parsing, zip, rpt

AH! I'm new to Python. Trying to get the pattern here, but could use some assistance to get unblocked.

**Scenario:**

- `testZip.zip` file with `test.rpt` files inside
- The .rpt files have **multiple** areas of interest ("AOI") to parse
- **AOI1**: Line starting with `$$`
- **AOI2**: Multiple lines starting with a single `$`

**Goal:**

- To get AOI's into tabular format for upload to SQL

**Sample file:**

```
$$ADD ID=TEST BATCHID='YEP' PASSWORD=NOPE
###########################################################################################
$KEY= 9/21/2020 3:53:55 PM/2002/B0/295.30/305.30/4FAOA973_3.0_v2.19.2.0_20150203_1/20201002110149
$TIMESTAMP= 20201002110149
$MORECOLUMNS=  more columns
$YETMORE = yay
```

**Tried so far:**

```
import zipfile

def get_aoi1(zip):
    z = zipfile.ZipFile(zip)
    for f in z.namelist():
        with z.open(f, 'r') as rptf:
            for l in rptf.readlines():
                if l.find(b"$$") != -1:
                    return l

def get_aoi2(zip):
    z = zipfile.ZipFile(zip)
    for f in z.namelist():
        with z.open(f, 'r') as rptf:
            for l in rptf.readlines():
                if l.find(b"$") != -1:
                    return l


aoi1 = get_aoi1('testZip.zip')
aoi2 = get_aoi2('testZip.zip')

print(aoi1)
print(aoi2)
```

**Results:**

- I get the same results for both functions

```
b"$$ADD ID=TEST BATCHID='YEP' PASSWORD=NOPE\r\n"
b"$$ADD ID=TEST BATCHID='YEP' PASSWORD=NOPE\r\n"
```

**How do I get the results in text instead of bytes (`b`) and remove the `\r\n` from `AOI1`?**

- There doesn't seem to be an `r` option for `z.open()`
- I've been unsuccessful with `.strip()`

**EDIT 1:**

- Thanks for the pep @furas!
- `return l.strip().decode()` worked for removing the new line and `b`

**How do I get the correct results from `AOI2` (lines with a single `$` in a tabular format)?**

**EDIT 2:**

- @furas 2021!
- Adding the following logic to `aoi2` function worked great.

```
col_array = []
    for l in rptf.readlines():
        if not l.startswith(b"$$") and l.startswith(b"$"):
            col_array.append(l)
    return col_array
```

Comment: `text = b"...".decode()`

Comment: string `$` you can find also in `$$` so it gives you first line instead of second in `get_aoi2`

Comment: **RE:** `text = b"...".decode()`: Where in the function is this placed?

Comment: what means `unsuccessful` ? Did you get error ? Why didn't show it in question ?

Comment: use `text = b"...".decode()` whenever you want to convert bytes to string/text

Comment: it is only example `text = b"...".decode()` - in your situation it can be ie. `text = aoi1.decode()`

Comment: if your data has always `$$` in first line and `$` in third and rest  lines then `aoi1 = rptf.readlines()[0]` and `aoi2 = "\t".join( rptf.readlines()[2:] )`

Comment: The `$$` and `$` will not reliably be on static lines.

Comment: Ideas for how to differentiate between a single `$` and multiple `$$`? Do you think `re` is the answer here?

Comment: I would first check if there is `$$` and later `$` - and this way I would know if there is only one `$` . And to make sure I would use `(not l.startswith('$$')) and l.startswith('$')`

Comment: or `if l[0] == "$" and l[1] != "$"`

Comment: Interesting... `if not l.startswith(b"$$") and l.startswith(b"$"):
                    return l.strip().decode()` only returns the first row `$KEY=...`, no subsequent rows (`$TIMESTAMP=`, `$MORECOLUMNS`, etc.)

Comment: becuaus you use `return` which finish function at once - after first maching line. You should run loop and add lines to list - and exit function after loop.

Comment: Bingo! See **Edit 2**. Thanks a bunch! You really helped.